# Encode byte[] via RSA using 'public key'

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, cryptography, rsa

We have the public key:

> -----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY----- MIIBCgKCAQEAwVACPi9w23mF3tBkdZz+zwrzKOaaQdr01vAbU4E1pvkfj4sqDsm6
>   lyDONS789sVoD/xCS9Y0hkkC3gtL1tSfTlgCMOOul9lcixlEKzwKENj1Yz/s7daS
>   an9tqw3bfUV/nqgbhGX81v/+7RFAEd+RwFnK7a+XYl9sluzHRyVVaTTveB2GazTw
>   Efzk2DWgkBluml8OREmvfraX3bkHZJTKX4EQSjBbbdJ2ZXIsRrYOXfaA+xayEGB+
>   8hdlLmAjbCVfaigxX0CDqWeR1yFL9kwd9P0NsZRPsmoqVwMbMu7mStFai6aIhc3n
>   Slv8kg9qv1m6XHVQY3PnEw+QQtqSIXklHwIDAQAB
>   -----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----

We have decoded it from Base64: there are 270 bytes.
Our input array has 255 bytes.
Our output (encrypted) array should be also 255 bytes.

We have tried the class RSACryptoServiceProvider. According to the MSDN we need to fill Modulus and Exponent, both are a public key (am I right?).

So we are confused... we have only this public key, where do we need to get exponent? Is is exponent part of that key? which part?

Comment: The naming (BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY) suggests that it contains an RSAPublicKey (as defined in PKCS#1) ASN.1 structure containing the modulus and public exponent. So you'd need to base64 decode then unpack the two numbers from the ASN.1.

Comment: Mikkel, thank you! How to define how many bytes are modulus and how many bytes are public exponent?

Comment: That's in the format. I would be surprised if there aren't tools for that in .net already. Maybe OpenSSL could also be used to read it and export the exponent and modulus.